# Infragistics UltraCombo Windows Controls Content did not displayed fully

Tags: .net, winforms, infragistics

I had developed with use of Infragistics control in starting up in run-time, only visible small area of the Combo control

only this much of content displayed

[image]

but i need to display full content in combo column

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem. I had to change control properties **`DropDownWidth`** and also Change **`DisplayLayout -> AutoFitStyle set ExtandLastColumn`**. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the .DropDownWith property

Comment: I am used multiple column in Dropdown, first column content displayed fully, but second, third,... column content displayed size for the header size only, did not displayed full content